# Drupal - Show user menu

Tags: php, drupal

I have box in my theme which shows either some text (probably block, not solved yet) or user menu ("navigation") if user is logged in.

However, I can't google how to get only user navigation and spit it out in my theme (I don't want to use '$left'. I want just the navigation)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it.

Following this tutorial: [Display or Print a Drupal block anywhere](http://www.ishmaelsanchez.com/display-or-print-drupal-block-anywhere) by [Ishmael Sanchez](http://www.ishmaelsanchez.com/),

I did following in my `page.tpl.php`:

```
<?php 
  $user_navigation = module_invoke('user', 'block', 'view', '1');
  print $user_navigation['content']; 
?>
```